# How to customize settings on Import Data Setup (Oracle)?

Tags: oracle

I have lots of CSV files to import with the same settings but it is different from the default settings, so every time that I have to import a file I also have to change everything.

I would like to ask if it's possible to customize the form of Import Data Setup.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, a **parameter file** might be what you are looking for. `PARFILE` is the keyword to be used (works both in EXPDP and IMPDP).

For example (from doc):

```
TABLES= countries, locations, regions
DUMPFILE=dpump_dir2:exp1.dmp,exp2%U.dmp
DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1
PARALLEL=3
```

More info in documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-F703B422-4584-493B-A5B3-651B40CDB765).